# mpirun does not consider -np parameter

Tags: c, mpi

here's a simple mpi program (I'm a beginner with it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int rank, size;
  char name[80];
  int length;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); // note that argc and argv are passed
                        // by address

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
  printf("size is: %d\n", size);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(name,&length);

  printf("Hello MPI: processor %d of %d on %s\n", rank,size,name);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I've compiled it with
mpicc -o ex1 file.c
but when I run it with
mpirun -np 10 ./ex1
it doesn't create 10 process as expected. Infact, for ten times, it writes:

Hello MPI: processor 0 of 1 on lory-SVE1513Q1ESI

I don't know why the size variable is set with 1.
I've tried to run it on a computer in my campus laboratory (ubuntu as mine) and it works correctly with:

Hello MPI: processor 0 of 10 on lory-SVE1513Q1ESI
Hello MPI: processor 1 of 10 on lory-SVE1513Q1ESI
Hello MPI: processor 2 of 10 on lory-SVE1513Q1ESI
...

what's the difference with my computer? :(

Comment: What implementation of MPI are you using on each computer?

Comment: Well, according to synaptic, I have installed two versions of MPI: openMPI and mpich2. Does it seem that OpenMPI might have some problems in Unix? Is mpich2 better? If so, what Shall I use OpenMPI for?